# Co-relation between non numeric and numeric variable

Tags: correlation, mixed-type-data

I am not good at stats. So accept my apology in advance if my question sounds silly or trivial.

I have two data sets. One contains the positive reviews of the app which includes rating given by the reviewer (i.e. 4 or 5), review text, and no of thumbs up given by other reviewers to the review. Similarly, other data set contains negative reviews which also includes the same columns, the only difference is that value of rating given by reviews is in between 1 to 3.

Now I want to find the correlation between thumbs-ups and positive reviews and also want to find the correlation between thumb ups and negative reviews. Based on some reading, I think to find the co-relation both variables should be numeric. In my case, the review data type is text, my question is can I use rating (which is numeric in nature) to find a correlation between thumb ups and positive and negative review? My hypothesis is that co-relation between negative reviews & thumb up would be stronger than co-relation between positive reviews & thumbs up

If not, is there any other way of testing above mentioned hypothesis

Comment: You can check **Spearman Coefficient**. I'll leave the link here since I see there is no need to paraphrase something well written. My contribution is to point to the source of your answer. > Spearman's coefficient is appropriate for both continuous and discrete
> ordinal variables. [Spearman's rank correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient)

Comment: Why did you split the dataset in two? Anyhow, I would start by visualizing the data. Maybe you can include a plot, with an edit to your post?